# Show only names that belong to a code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in my app a guest searches for their RSVP code in the code/index.html page then clicks on a continue link that brings them to the rsvp page. I am trying to show only names that belong to the specific code on the RSVP but currently all names are showing up. I have passed the code as a param in the link on the index page but when I get to the rsvp page it is showing up in the url with a period which doesn't seem right ex: /rsvp.1
so I am guessing that this is where I am going wrong but I cant figure out why:

associations

```
Guest belongs_to :code
Code has_many :guest
```

code/index.html.erb
(page with the link that takes user to rsvp page and passes the params to rsvp page)

```
<h2><%= link_to 'Continue', rsvp_path(code) %></h2>
```

code_controller

```
    def index
      @codes = Code.search(params[:search])
    end 
    def rsvp
      code_id = params[:code]
      @guests = Guest.where("code_id", "#{code_id}")

    end
```

code/rsvp.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <form class="row form-inline">
         <% @guests.each do |guest| %>
            <%= guest.name %>
         <% end %>
         <div class="form-group">
          <p> Will you be attending the wedding of Kristen Albrecht and Chris Alford September 1, 2017? </p>
         <button aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" ngbdropdowntoggle="" type="button" aria-expanded="false">
          Yes</button>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
         </div>
          </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes

```
  resources :codes
  resources :guests
  get '/code' =>'codes#code'
  get '/rsvp' =>'codes#rsvp'
```

Comment: Can you show your `routes.rb` file please?

Comment: @GregAnswer I have added the routes

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out:

I changed the link on the index page to

```
 <%= link_to "Continue", {:controller => "codes", :action => "rsvp", :code_id => code.id }%>
```

then I changed the controller code to

```
  def rsvp
    @guests = Guest.where(code_id: params[:code_id]) 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that `code` is a parameter in the URL, you have to make the following changes:

### routes.rb

```
get '/rsvp/:code' =>'codes#rsvp'
```

### code/index.html.erb

```
<h2><%= link_to 'Continue', rsvp_path(code: code) %></h2>
```

This way `params[:code]` will have a value in the code_controller